# Excel, align duplicates + other data

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have 3 columns

```
A    | B   | C
00046|00046| Description
00046|00056| Description2
00046|00078| Description3
00056|     |
00056|     |
00078|     |
```

they have to become in column:

```
A    |  D  |     F
00046|00046| Description
00046|00046| Description
00046|00046| Description
00056|00056| Description2
00056|00056| Description2
00078|00078| Description3
```

How can i do that? I have this formula, but it works only with one column, not the column description.

```
=IF(INDEX($L:$L;MATCH($F2;L:$L;0));"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D1: =A1
E1: =VLOOKUP(D1,$B$1:$C$3,2,FALSE)
```

Select `d1:e1` and fill down

[image]

Comment: Not working, https://gyazo.com/53906d8d50f538c8a317f506cf53b167

Comment: @staff614 you do need to translate functions into your language!

Comment: @staff614 eg. If your Excel is Portuguese, it might translate to `=PROCV(D1;$B$1:$C$3;2;FALSO)` *according to the Microsoft formula translator*

Comment: I had translated to italian and wasn't working, neither with the ';', but it's ok, im using english excel and it's working now, thanks !